# Custom QGraphicItem and Repaint Issues

Tags: c++, qt

All, I implemented a QGraphicsItem which is a polygon.  I sped up development by using `QGraphicsEllipseItem` as the points (for the dragging capabilities.)  However, I am now having difficulty in `update()` functionality.  My code is posted at the end, my questions are:

1. Am I taking the right approach here?  I am starting to doubt myself
2. Am I supposed to be calling `QGraphicsItem::update()` in my implementation?  I call it alot

Some other info:

- I did a dirty little hack.  In my actual code I also inherit from `QObject`.  This allows me to install an `eventFilter` on the scene() (which I know has been set using `itemChange`).  From the scene I filter `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` during mouse moves and call `QGraphicsItem::update()` otherwise my lines wouldn't be redrawn.
- When I remove my `InteractivePolygon` from the scene now, my lines are not removed!  I have to call scene()->update.  I feel like something's not right.

---

declaration:

```
class InteractivePolygon : public QGraphicsItem
{

public:
   //Only important methods
   QRectF boundingRect() const;
   void paint(bla bla bla);
   bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *);

private:
   QList<QGraphicsEllipseItem *> m_points;

   void AddPolygonPoint(QPointF);
   QGraphicsEllipseItem * MakeNewPoint(QPointF);
}
```

implementation:

```
QRectF InteractivePolygon::boundingRect() const
{
   return childrenBoundingRect();
}

void InteractivePolygon::paint(QPainter painter.. otherstuf)
{
   QPen line_pen(QColor(255,0,0));
   painter->setPen(line_pen);

   if(m_points.count() > 1)
   {
      for(int i = 1; i < m_points.count(); ++i)
          painter->drawLine(m_points[i-1]->pos(), m_points[i]->pos());
   }
}

void AddPolygonPoint(QRectF point)
{
   QGraphicsEllipseItem * new_item = MakeNewPoint(point);
   new_item->setParent(this);

   m_points->push_front(new_item);

   update();  
}

QGraphicsEllipseItem * InteractivePolygon::MakeNewPoint(QPointF & new_point)
{
   QGraphicsEllipseItem * result = 0;
   result = new QGraphicsEllipseItem();
   result->setPos(new_point);
   result->setRect(-4, -4, 8, 8);
   result->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable)

   return result;
}

//Lets pretend this method is correctly setup/exists
bool InteractivePolygon::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
   if(event->type() == QEvent::QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove)
   {
      QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouse_move = (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *)event;
      //Selected index is set else, let's assume it works
      if(selected_index)
      {
         update(); //If I don't do this, my lines in my paint() are not redrawn.
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was `prepareGeometryChange()` everytime I changed anything in my item that would change its bounding box.  Everything is redrawn correctly and updated as necessary.

This allowed me to remove all `update()` calls.