# QGraphicsItem::SetCursor Won't Deselect

Tags: c++, qt

All,

I have a `QGraphicsEllipseItem` with `setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsMovable)`.  This allows me drag and move ellipses quickly in a QGraphicsView.

I decided to be fancy, and `setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor)` to let the user know they can move it by clicking.  However, now it won't let go when I let go of the left mouse button?  What am I doing wrong?

---

Example code: [Custom QGraphicItem and Repaint Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278281/custom-qgraphicitem-and-repaint-issues)

**Note:** I removed the `update()` calls, and added `prepareGeometryChange()` calls.
Now modify the `MakeNewPoint` function:

```
QGraphicsEllipseItem * InteractivePolygon::MakeNewPoint(QPointF & new_point)
{
   QGraphicsEllipseItem * result = 0;
   result = new QGraphicsEllipseItem();
   result->setPos(new_point);
   result->setRect(-4, -4, 8, 8);
   result->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable)
   result->setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor); //Setting this removes my ability to let go of an item. NOTE: result is parented by this.

   return result;
}
```

later:

```
 QGraphicsEllipseItem * new_item = MakeNewPoint(bla);
 new_item->setParent(this);
 //add it to my QList<QGraphicsEllipseItem *> m_points;
```

---

I would like to note that my `QGraphicsEllipseItem` is parented by a custom `QGraphicsItem`.  I don't change the parents/Custom Item cursor, only the ellipse's.  I do not experience this problem with non parented ellipses...

---

**Interesting result:** So my class custom `QGraphicsItem` class (the parent of the ellipses) is a QObject so I can filter incoming mouse events from the scene.  I did a `setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor)` in my custom class's constructor... and here's where it gets interesting:

The eventFilter now catches `(event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove)` even if a mouse button isn't pressed down.  If I don't have the `setCursor` call, that event only fires while a mouse button is pressed... thoughts?

Comment: Could you provide some more details or code sample ? It's working fine for me

Comment: "now it won't let go when I let go" The drag operation does not complete, or the cursor will not unset?

Comment: It also works fine for me. Are you subclassing QGraphicsEllipseItem? If so, are you reimplementing any of the mouse event handlers?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278281/custom-qgraphicitem-and-repaint-issues -- I subclass the QGraphicsItem and QObject class to make a polygon.  I have indeed installed an event filter.

Comment: @cmannett85 I am hesitant to say the drag operation does not complete as I do not use QDrag... the cursor will not unset.  I let go of the mouse button and `QGraphicsEllipseItem` still moves with the cursor.

Comment: I think this question is a bit too localized to answer. In cases like this it is best to start with a minimal compilable example that works, and then make that example more and more like your actual code until it stops working the way you want it to. Then you can figure out the problem.

Comment: I was afraid of that, I was hoping I was doing something dumb... Would you happen to know what handles the mousePress/Move/Release when `Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsMovable` are set.  Is that `QGraphicScene` or `QGraphicsItem`

Comment: They both have their own implementations. I'm fairly certain that when ItemIsSelectable and ItemIsMovable are set, the QGraphicsItem handles itself, though.

Comment: Okay I narrowed it down, when I `setCursor` on my class or any of its children, my class becomes the scene's `mouseGrabberItem()` and never releases it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay got it, here's what's happening, it's intuitive once you realize it:

When you set that a `QGraphicsItem` to a unique cursor, the `QGraphicsView` has to `setMouseTracking(true)` otherwise the `QGraphicsScene` will never know when to change the cursor (ie when it's over the graphics item with the unique cursor.)  The mouse move events were affecting my ellipse.

Normally, the `QGraphicsScene` only gets mouse move events when a button is held down.